# Symfony assert callback dont work on in admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, symfony-validator

`@Assert\Callback` doesn't work and I don't understand why, what am I doing wrong? I want to check that there is at least one value in the `competitionTypes` field. In other entities of the project, validation works, it doesn't work specifically in this entity.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="experience_in_competition")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class ExperienceInCompetition
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="value is invalid(field must be non empty)",
     *     groups={"KNS-2020-2"}
     *     )
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="year", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $year;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="NKO\OrderBundle\Entity\Application\KNS\SecondStage2020\CompetitionType")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="application_competition_type",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *         inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="competition_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $competitionTypes;

    public function __construct(string $year)
    {
        $this->setYear($year);
        $this->competitionTypes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function isValidCompetitionType(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        if ($this->getCompetitionType()->isEmpty()) {
            $context->buildViolation('value is invalid(field must be non empty)')
                ->atPath('competitionTypes')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Admin class:

```
class ExperienceInCompetitionAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('year', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Год',
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => true
            ])
            ->add('competitionType', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => CompetitionType::class,
                'label' => 'Конкурс',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->andWhere('u.code = :name')
                        ->setParameters(['name' => ApplicationTypes::KNS_APPLICATION_SECOND_STAGE_2020]);
                },
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Values from this entity are not validated, I tried to insert groups into `@Assert\Callback` as for field `$year`, it didn't help.
An entry of this kind did not help either:

```
 * @Assert\Count(
 *     min="1",
 *     minMessage="value is invalid(field must be non empty)",
 *     groups={
 *         "KNS-2020-2"
 *     }
 * )
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Is your callback method actually called?

Comment: callback is not called. Why might the callback fail?

Comment: How is the validation process started?

Comment: $form->handleRequest($request); if ($form->isSubmitted()) { $isFormValid = $form->isValid(); }

Comment: Maybe your form is not configured with data_class option?

Comment: data_class was not set anywhere before, but the validation worked. I tried it - it didn't help either.

Comment: Is your data validated in the default group or did you configure some validation groups in your form?